# Shuffling in a gridview

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, imageview, shuffle

I am having trouble with shuffling images in a gridview. I am makin a npuzzle slider and can only slide the blank image. The main problem is that i set tags on my imageview in the gridviewadapter. But if i shuffle the images, these tags will stay the same but are supposed to change with the images. So for example

Suppose i got a bitmaparraylist of bitmaps: {bm0,bm1,bm2,bm3,bm4,bm5,bm6,bm7,bm8} and i set the tags {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} in my image adapter. if i shuffle this bitmap, how am i supposed to shuffle the imagetags with them?

Here is the code of my imageAdapter:

```
private ArrayList<Bitmap> crops;
private List ID;
private Context mContext;

public ImageAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Bitmap> crops, List ID) {
    mContext = c;
    this.crops = crops;
    this.ID = ID;
}

public int getCount() {
    return crops.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageBitmap(crops.get(position));
    imageView.setTag(position);
    return imageView;
}
```

}

As you can see the tags will always be the same, but that will cause problems. :(

Any hints tricks or tips on solving this?

PS: I made a List id's but didn't do anything with it because i didn't know what to do

Kees

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle a list or any other collection like this

```
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Collections.shuffle(bitmaparraylist , new Random(seed));
```

After this call adapter's notifydatasetchanged method. You don't need to set tag of ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

As I put collections.shuffle () to the images in a GridView?
imageIDs serves me as a reference for the shuffle () and must first pass to arrayList? I know that random is more complicated so I prefer to use collections.shuffle ().

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    Integer [] imageIDs;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c, int ...pos){
        mContext = c;

        imageIDs = new Integer[pos.length];//it's for set the number items
        for (int i=0; i<pos.length; i++){
            if (i<mThumbIds.length-1){
                imageIDs[i]=mThumbIds[pos[i]];
            }
        }
        //_____________________________
    }

    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.alemania_2006, R.drawable.arg_1978, R.drawable.brasil_2014,
            R.drawable.francia_1998, R.drawable.rusia_2018, R.drawable.sudafrica_2010
    };



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageIDs.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return imageIDs[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null){
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(350, 350));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(4, 4, 4, 4);
        }else{
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);


        return imageView;
    }
}


public class Playing extends AppCompatActivity{

    int []img={0,1,2,3,4,5};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_playing);



        GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, img));

        gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(Playing.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //cambiar de vista la imagen al clickear:
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add method in adapter

```
public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(crops, new Random(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
```

and call

```
imageAdapter.shuffle();
imageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```